# Is it wrong to have count(*) as part of the select query

Tags: mysql, sql

```
select id, first_name, count(*) from users;
```

The users table contains 10 entries, but the above select query shows only a single row. Is it wrong to mix count(*) as part of the above query?

Comment: Any reason why this has to be done in a single query?

Comment: The absence of window aggregate functions in MySQL forces you to read the users table twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[COUNT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count) is a function that aggregates. You can't mix it into your normal query.

If you want to receive the ten entries just do a normal select:

```
SELECT id, name FROM users;
```

and to get the number of entries:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM users;
```

Answer (score 2):

Its becuase you are using an aggregate function in the select part of the query,

to return the 10 records you just need the id, and first_name in the query.

EG:

```
SELECT id, first_Name
FROM users
```

if you wanted to get a count of the records in the table then you could use

```
SELECT (Count(id))
FROM [users]
```

Comment: (add the word 'aggregate' before 'function', and I'll give you a +1 cookie) - granted

Comment: @Jeff Parker - as requested :)

Answer (score 2):

It's not "wrong", but it is meaningless without a "group by" clause - most databases will reject that query, as aggregate functions should include a group by if you're including other columns.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly what you're trying to achieve with this?

```
select id, first_name,(select count(*) from users) AS usercount from users;
```

will give each individual user and the total count but again, not sure why you would want it.

Answer (score 1):

```
select id, first_name from users,(select count(*) as total from users) as t;
```

Answer (score 1):

`COUNT` is an **aggregate function** and it will always give you count of all records in table unless used in combination with **group by**.

If you use it in combination with normal query, then it will take priority in deciding the final output as in your case it returns 1.

If you want to return all 10 records, you should just write -

```
select id,first_name from users
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need number of rows in a table, you can use MySQL's SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS clause. Check MySQL docs to see how it's used.